# Rspec - Undefined method 'allow'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stubbing

I am trying to stub the env variable to access *Rails.env.production?*

```
context 'Rails environment is production' do
  it 'returns the correct api production service' do
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('RAILS_ENV').and_return('production')
    expect(application.api_domain).to eql('https://api.some_url.com')
  end
end
```

but I always get this error

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `allow' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::CesidApplication::CesidApplication::RailsEnvironmentIsDevelopment:0x00007fcc48cec518>
   Did you mean?  all
```

Module method im testing

```
module Cesid
  module Application
    def api_domain
     uri = URI.parse(marketing_suite_url)
     domain = PublicSuffix.parse(uri.host)
     Rails.env.production? ? "https://api.#{domain.name}" : "https://api-#{domain.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec version

```
3.5.4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the entire spec file or just a fragment? This isn't really a normal behavior as the RSpec mocks methods should be available in both example groups and constructs like let and before. Is the issue specific to this spec?

Comment: Additionally stubbing ENV is a bit to high up the chain IMHO. I would just do `allow(Rails).to receive_message_chain("env.production?") { true }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the `expect` syntax in `spec_helper.rb` like:

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
end
```

Then the `allow` will work